# Minimum L1 norm of gradient

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Is there an easy way to find what the minimum possible value of $\int |\nabla \phi|$ is for $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function whose support is contained in the open unit ball and so that $\int \phi = 1$?

I saw such an integral come up in a proof of regularity estimates for solutions to Laplace's equation, and knowing the minimum possible value of this integral would help me determine what the sharpest possible constant in that regularity estimate is.

Comment: Using $1-$distance to the origin is constant gradient. You can smooth out the origin and the boundary without changing much. This feels extremal. After normalization, this gives a value of $n+1$

Comment: Actually, thinking a bit more, you can do better with a trapezoid like structure. Let $f(r)=1$ if $r<1-1/m$. Otherwise $f(r)=m*(1-r)$. Take the limit as m goes to infinity. I think this gives you a value of $n$.

Comment: You can take a radial average without increasing the gradient, so you can assume it’s radial. Then you need to minimize the integral of $r^{n}|f’(x)|$ given that the integral of $r^n f(x)$ is fixed. You can do integration by parts and that $r \leq 1$ to prove the $n$ bound.

Comment: In the title you've asked for the minimum of the $L^1$ norm of the gradient, but in your question you have the $L^1$ norm of the laplacian. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$ m: = \inf_{v \in \mathcal{A}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\vert D u \vert dx $$ where $\mathcal{A} = \{v \in C^\infty_0(B_1) \, \vert \, \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} v d x =1 \}$.

As Eric suggested in the comments, $m=n$. I will present his arguments here rigorously.

First, we prove $m \geqslant n$. For $u \in \mathcal{A}$, \begin{align*}
1 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u d x \\
&= \int_{B_1} uD_i x_i d x \\
&= - \int_{B_1}x_i D_i u d x 
\end{align*} via integration by parts. Summing over $i$ from 1 to $n$ gives $$n = - \int_{B_1} x \cdot D u d x \leqslant \int_{B_1} \vert x \vert \cdot \vert Du \vert dx \leqslant \int_{B_1} \vert Du \vert dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\vert Du \vert dx.$$ Hence, $m \geqslant n$.

Secondly, we show $m \leqslant n$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ be sufficiently small and let $ \phi_{\varepsilon} \in C^\infty_0([0,\infty))$ be a bump function such that $$ 
\begin{cases}
\phi_{\varepsilon} (r) =1 \text{ if } 0\leqslant r \leqslant 1-\varepsilon \\
\phi_{\varepsilon} (r) =0 \text{ if }  r\geqslant 1  \\
0 \leqslant \phi_{\varepsilon} \leqslant 1\\
\vert \phi_{\varepsilon}' (r) \vert \leqslant 1/\varepsilon + \varepsilon.
\end{cases}  $$ Consider the sequence $u_\varepsilon: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $u_\varepsilon(x) = C_\varepsilon\phi_{\varepsilon}(\vert x \vert)$ where $C_\varepsilon$ is chosen so that $\int_{B_1}u_\varepsilon d x =1 $. Clearly, $\{u_\varepsilon \} \subset \mathcal{A} $. Observe that using polar coordinates implies \begin{align*} 
1 &= C_\varepsilon \int_{B_1} \phi_{\varepsilon}(\vert x \vert) d x \\
&= n \omega_n C_\varepsilon \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \phi_{\varepsilon}(r) d r
\end{align*} where $\omega_n$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\phi_\varepsilon (r) \leqslant 1$ for $r\in[0,1]$, dominated convergence implies $$ \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \phi_{\varepsilon}(r) d r \to \int_0^1 r^{n-1}  d r = \frac 1 n $$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, so $C_\varepsilon \to 1 / \omega_n$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Next, we may calculate that $\vert Du_\varepsilon \vert = C_\varepsilon \vert \phi ' ( \vert x \vert ) \vert $, so again via polar coordinates \begin{align*}
\int_{B_1} \vert Du_\varepsilon \vert d x &= n \omega_n C_\varepsilon  \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \vert \phi ' ( r ) \vert d r \\
&= n \omega_n C_\varepsilon  \int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 r^{n-1} \vert \phi ' ( r ) \vert d r \\
&\leqslant n \omega_n C_\varepsilon  \int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 r^{n-1} \vert \phi ' ( r ) \vert d r \\
&\leqslant n \omega_n C_\varepsilon  \int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 r^{n-1} \bigg (\frac 1 \varepsilon + \varepsilon \bigg ) d r \\
&= \omega_n C_\varepsilon\bigg (\frac 1 \varepsilon + \varepsilon \bigg ) ( 1- (1-\varepsilon)^n) \to n
\end{align*} as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Thus, by the squeeze theorem, $$ \int_{B_1} \vert Du_\varepsilon \vert d x  \to n$$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, so $m \leqslant n$ as desired.